# Telerik ListView RadListViewItemDragDropEventArgs has an empty DestinationHtmlElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm implementing drag & drop with a Telerik RadListView (ASP.NET controls) and when I perform the drap and drop I don't get any data in the EventArgs of the server event (ItemDrop) that tell me where it was dropped i.e. from the DestinationHtmlElement inside the RadListViewItemDragDropEventArgs.

This is my control markup:

```
 <telerik:RadListView ID="ListViewGallery" runat="server"
                OnItemDrop="ListViewGallery_ItemDrop"
                AllowPaging="true"
                OnNeedDataSource="ListViewGallery_NeedDataSource"
                AllowReorder="true"
                DataKeyNames="FileId">
                <ClientSettings AllowItemsDragDrop="true"></ClientSettings>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="rlvI productItemWrapper">
                        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background; background: url('<%#Eval("Photo") %>')  no-repeat center center; background-size: contain;">
                            <telerik:RadListViewItemDragHandle ID="RadListViewItemDragHandle1" runat="server" ToolTip="Drag to organize" CssClass="move-item" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div class="RadListView RadListViewFloated">
                        <div class="rlvFloated rlvAutoScroll">
                            <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <telerik:RadDataPager ID="RadDataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="20">
                            <Fields>
                                <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric"></telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField>
                            </Fields>
                        </telerik:RadDataPager>
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
            </telerik:RadListView>
```

On the server side I just have this event handler:

```
 protected void ListViewGallery_ItemDrop(object sender, RadListViewItemDragDropEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

I thought it might be to do with not assigning the data correctly but I have made sure the DataKeyNames property of the list view is set.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I've just realised I have been missing a part of this. I want to drag it into itself to change the order of the items. The [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/itemdragdrop/defaultcs.aspx) has the drop outside of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I figured it out.

To achieve this and to work out any css quirks I did the following:

1. I included a container inside the element with a class of rlvI (which you need to do for the drag and drop to work as per the Telerik website - see link in original post);
2. Inside this container I had to include a transparent image to take up the entire space and I floated this so as to remove it form the normal flow - I'm sure I could do this better but it is largely irrelevant for this exercise. You just need something inside it to drop "onto";
3. This internal image needs a unique Id so when it drops the event tells you where it was dropped;
4. Now the dropping works and I get the DestinationHtmlElement as the image client id of the one I dropped onto. Using this and the index of where it came from (from the DataItem.DataItemIndex of the event args) I can re order my list like so:

   ```
    protected void ListViewGallery_ItemDrop(object sender, RadListViewItemDragDropEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.DestinationHtmlElement.IndexOf("img-drop-zone") < 0)
       {
           return;
       }

       int newIndex = int.Parse(e.DestinationHtmlElement.Split('-').Last());
       int oldIndex = e.DraggedItem.DataItemIndex;

       ImagesList = MediaItem.MoveItem(ImagesList, (short)oldIndex, (short)newIndex);
       ListViewGallery.Rebind();
    }
   ```

The MoveItem method of MediaItem was fairly simple to write. If anyone is interested I can add it here but it essentially just re-adjusts the order property of the List items to reflect the move.

Comment: I had to delete my previous comment :) great post :) Perhaps you can make a code library sample out of it (post it here http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/aspnet-ajax/listview) and get some Telerik points.